# How to get browserName in protractor

Tags: protractor, test-configration

Hi i want to get browser name in the onPrepare function,

I used the below code.

```
browser.getCapabilities().then((c) => {

      c.get('browserName');
});
```

the code writes the browser name properly on the console if i use:

```
browser.getCapabilities().then((c) => {

          console.log(c.get('browserName'));
    });
```

But i gets 'undefined' on, return , set to a variable or set to browser.browserName. Could someone help me here

I tried below three methods:

```
var a;

    browser.getCapabilities().then((c) => {

          a= c.get('browserName');
    });



var a=  browser.getCapabilities().then((c) => {

              return c.get('browserName');
        });



global.a;

    browser.getCapabilities().then((c) => {

          global.a= c.get('browserName');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try [browser.getProcessedConfig](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.getProcessedConfig) instead of `getCapabilities`, because I cant find that in the Protractor API documentation.

> Get the processed configuration object that is currently being run.
>   This will contain the specs and capabilities properties of the current
>   runner instance.
>
> https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.getProcessedConfig

Code example:

```
  onPrepare: function() {
    return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(data => {
      global.deviceName = data.capabilities.browserName;
    });
  }
```

Based on a code example from:

- https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4719
- https://github.com/IgorSasovets/get-config-capabilities

Comment: Hi this returns a managed promise, ManagedPromise::89 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}

Comment: I want to get the browser name and use it in next line

Comment: @PDHide I am not a protractor user, so i cannot make a working example. Updated my code example and added another link that might help.

Comment: What happens if i don't use the return keyword?

Comment: Try? I think you should find a JavaScript developer close by, because the async nature of JavaScript is sometimes hard to initially grasp. The promise is a way to handle the async nature of JavaScript if you know how to work with them. Just randomly doing trail and error wont overcome this probably.